# I want to search element listed single cell using node js in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I want to fetch all users details stored in `users` table, if his email and provided any code from code list (we will provide codes to him at the time of signup) will match

The unique codes stored in single cell named `codes` and I want to search for `'SNngyCbU4xuIJVh7'` (third one)

`"O8g5Sd24kh9ymW2G","gkkxcCkN0PMA91Av","SNngyCbU4xuIJVh7"`

Query for email and codes

```
db.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM users '+
'WHERE code='+"'"+code+"' AND "+
' email= ' + "'" + email + "'").then(function(app){
```

Please help me with right MySQL query, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

> `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`
>
> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string `str` is in the string list `strlist` consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by `,` characters.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:code, codes) AND email = :email
```

In your existing code:

```
db.sequelize.query(
    "SELECT *"
    + " FROM users"
    + " WHERE FIND_IN_SET('" + code + "', codes) AND email= '" + email + "'"
).then(function(app){ ... }
```

Note: people tend to use `'` to define strings in SQL instead of `"`, since this is supported in all RDBMS. I changed your code to make use of that convention.

Note 2: from your question it is unclear whether the column that contains the codes is named `code` or `codes`. I picked the second option since it seems to make more sense.

---

If your data contains embedded double quotes, you can proceed as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT('"', :code, '"'), codes) AND email = :email
```

In sequelize (using backticks to avoid the need to escape the double quotes):

```
db.sequelize.query(
    `SELECT *`
    + ` FROM users`
    + ` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('"` + code + `"', codes) AND email= '` + email + `'`
).then(function(app){ ... }
```

Comment: Above mention code working  only if code separated with **comma**
hihodvglEKWyeP5b,EkopeihtIQNDUwkH,vf2CiIyy5ztpnyRU,

Comment: Not working with **Double quote** with **comma**
"xTZNiuiKsp1XvzvK","yZZTwwTo87GrcT1S","E3g6b6tqac8l8u0M"

Comment: @saurabhkumar: ok, I understand. You can add double quotes around `code` before using it in `FIND_IN_SET()`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think one opening bracket missed here, or something wrong 
+ ` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('"` + code + `"'), codes) AND email= '` + email + `'`

Comment: @saurabhkumar: yep, that's a typo, sorry about that. I remove the superfluous closing parenthesis.

Comment: Got " SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token "

After adding mentioned quotes